Lots of errors trying to update nvidia drivers with dnf update --refresh on Fedora 39
So about a week or two ago I tried updating my kernel which incidentally broke my NVIDIA Drivers somehow. Every startup I'd get the "NVIDIA Kernel module broken. Reverting to nouveau" message or something along those lines. Looked it up and was told by multiple sources to sudo dnf update --refresh, but doing so gave me:
 Problem 1: package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia(x86-64) = 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 2: package akmod-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver requires nvidia-kmod-common >= 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package akmod-nvidia-3:535.129.03-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 3: package nvidia-kmod-common-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.noarch from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 requires nvidia-kmod = 3:550.54.15, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nvidia-driver-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 requires nvidia-kmod-common = 3:550.54.15, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kmod-nvidia-open-dkms-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System conflicts with kmod-nvidia-latest-dkms provided by kmod-nvidia-latest-dkms-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package kmod-nvidia-open-dkms-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package kmod-nvidia-open-dkms-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 4: package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia(x86-64) = 3:550.54.14, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System requires nvidia-modprobe(x86-64) = 3:550.54.14, but none of the providers can be installed
  - problem with installed package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - cannot install both nvidia-modprobe-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 and nvidia-modprobe-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both nvidia-modprobe-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 and nvidia-modprobe-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia(x86-64) = 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia(x86-64) = 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package nvidia-modprobe-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 5: problem with installed package akmod-nvidia-3:535.129.03-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:535.129.03-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc = 3:535.129.03, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:535.129.03-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc = 3:535.129.03, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver and xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc-3:535.129.03-2.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver and xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc-3:535.129.03-2.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver requires nvidia-kmod-common >= 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates requires nvidia-kmod-common >= 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc-3:535.129.03-2.fc39.x86_64
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 6: problem with installed package kmod-nvidia-open-dkms-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package kmod-nvidia-open-dkms-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System requires nvidia-kmod-common = 3:550.54.14, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kmod-nvidia-open-dkms-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 requires nvidia-kmod-common = 3:550.54.14, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nvidia-kmod-common-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.noarch from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 requires nvidia-driver = 3:550.54.14, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both nvidia-driver-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 and nvidia-driver-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System requires nvidia-settings(x86-64) = 3:550.54.14, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nvidia-settings-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 requires nvidia-driver(x86-64) = 3:550.54.15, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both nvidia-settings-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 and nvidia-settings-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from @System
  - cannot install both nvidia-settings-3:550.54.15-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64 and nvidia-settings-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64 from cuda-fedora39-x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package nvidia-settings-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                 Architecture                       Version                                         Repository                                                   Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):
 kmod-nvidia-latest-dkms                                 x86_64                             3:550.54.15-1.fc39                              cuda-fedora39-x86_64                                         40 M
 nvidia-driver                                           x86_64                             3:550.54.14-1.fc39                              cuda-fedora39-x86_64                                        126 M
 nvidia-driver                                           x86_64                             3:550.54.15-1.fc39                              cuda-fedora39-x86_64                                        126 M
 nvidia-modprobe                                         x86_64                             3:550.54.15-1.fc39                              cuda-fedora39-x86_64                                         30 k
 nvidia-settings                                         x86_64                             3:550.54.15-1.fc39                              cuda-fedora39-x86_64                                        822 k
 xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc                             x86_64                             3:550.67-1.fc39                                 rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver                              44 M
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 akmod-nvidia                                            x86_64                             3:550.67-1.fc39                                 rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                    40 k
 nvidia-kmod-common                                      noarch                             3:550.54.14-1.fc39                              cuda-fedora39-x86_64                                         12 k
 nvidia-kmod-common                                      noarch                             3:550.54.15-1.fc39                              cuda-fedora39-x86_64                                         12 k
 xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power                               x86_64                             3:550.67-1.fc39                                 rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver                             103 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Skip  10 Packages

Nothing to do.
Complete!

Did what it said and tried adding --best --allowerasing
 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - problem with installed package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.54.14-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia(x86-64) = 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-power-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates requires xorg-x11-drv-nvidia(x86-64) = 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 2: problem with installed package akmod-nvidia-3:535.129.03-1.fc39.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package akmod-nvidia-3:535.129.03-1.fc39.x86_64
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver requires nvidia-kmod-common >= 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package akmod-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates requires nvidia-kmod-common >= 3:550.67, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-3:550.67-1.fc39.x86_64 from rpmfusion-nonfree-updates is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)

Doing all this because ever since the Kernel broke, I haven't been able to run any CUDA code. I tried running NVIDIA's Vector Addition sample and got this error:
Failed to allocate device vector A (error code system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination)!
If I try running my own vector output CUDA program, it just outputs 0. Needless to say CUDA is not working. I checked my CUDA Toolkit and even reinstalled it so that should be fine. For all I know I might not be even in the ballpark of what I should be doing to fix this. Ultimate goal is to get my CUDA code working again.
Things I tried:

Reinstalling CUDA Toolkit
sudo dnf update --refresh
sudo dnf update --refresh --best --allowerasing
Signing the NVIDIA kernel module (can't remember where but some place said to try it, I followed this guide)
Completely reinstalling drivers (through this guide)
Reverting to an older kernel (this worked for a while but broke eventually too in the same way, plus I'd rather not be stuck on an older kernel if I can fix the issue)

Pretty much all of these had no effect

does -allowerasing work?

option 1


If some of your packages have unsatisfied dependencies, the upgrade will refuse to continue until you run it again with an extra --allowerasing option. This often happens with packages installed from third-party repositories for which an updated repositories hasn't been yet published. Please study the output very carefully and examine which packages are going to be removed. None of them should be essential for system functionality, but some of them might be important for your productivity.

In case of unsatisfied dependencies, you can sometimes see more details if you add --best option to the command line.
If you want to remove/install some packages manually before running dnf system-upgrade download again, it's advisable to perform those operations with --setopt=keepcache=1 dnf command line option. Otherwise the whole package cache will be removed after your operation, and you'll need to download all the packages once again.


https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade
source
option 2

sudo dnf clean dbcache
Removes cache files generated from the repository metadata.
This forces DNF to regenerate the cache files the next time it is
run.
sudo dnf clean expire-cache
Marks the repository metadata expired. DNF will re-validate the
cache for each repository the next time it is used.
sudo dnf clean metadata
Removes repository metadata. Those are the files which DNF uses
to determine the remote availability of packages. Using this op‐
tion will make DNF download all the metadata the next time it is
run.
sudo dnf --refresh install nvidiadriver
source
